# Smart capture (SFMC) vs Survey (SFMCP)

Tags: smart-capture, survey, dynamic-forms

What is the best way to manage web forms (smart capture in marketing cloud vs Survey in interaction studio), I understand surveys is more to run web personalisation but as standard web forms. Any recommendations or thoughts?

we are looking for a solution to manage the volume of forms with less effort.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.